# Prediction / Foreshadowing - Adverb

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, adverbs

What is a way to say "as you _____ mentioned" where _____ is meant to convey that the person correctly predicted / foreshadowed your response?

Comment: *...as you **previously** mentioned,* perhaps.

Comment: You need an *adverbial* form, but idiomatically it's not really credible to say *"as you predictively mentioned"* (and *foreshadowingly* is a complete no-no, obviously). You might consider ***portentiously***, but that generally carries connotations of ***ominously** predicting*. Besides which it's a bit "stuffy" (as would be *presagiously, presagefully, prefiguratively*).

Comment: I'd say "as you will have mentioned".

Comment: @anemone: Regardless of whether you use simple past or future perfect (or even simple present), nothing about that would particularly imply *anticipatory*, which OP is specifically interested in.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Isn't OP asking for a _verb_, though? And I'd say "you will have done st." does express a fair level of certainty...

Comment: @anemone: OP already *has* a verb ("mentioned"). So any word that goes *before* it pretty much has to be an *adverbial* form in order to modify the verb.

Answer (score 1):

If they actually predicted something beforehand, you could say that they "presciently" mentioned it.  To be "prescient" is to see or predict the future.

Answer (score -1):

I skimmed the general area of relevant ***pre-*** words in OED, but saw nothing suitable. I'd go for...

> *As you [anticipatively](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anticipatively) mentioned...*

(OED **anticipatively**: *By way of anticipation.*)

---

In most contexts, doing something *anticipatively* would normally be understood to imply doing it *deliberately* (with conscious knowledge of a relationship between what you're doing now and what you expect later). There might be a more "passive" equivalent term (i.e. - without those "volitional" implications), but I can't think of one. If it was important to avoid the unwanted connotations, I'd probably use more words: *"As you **unconsciously** anticipated [when you mentioned blah blah]"*.

Of course, in OP's *exact* context it's quite likely I wouldn't bother to explicitly reference anything to do with "foreshadowing" since it's contextually obvious. I think I might well prefer...

> *As you [perspicaciously](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/perspicaciously) mentioned...*

...which peripherally implies "foretellingly" (etymologically, Latin *perspicax* "sharp-sighted, having the power of seeing through; acute"), in that you (in the past) were able to see through to a future time when your point would be highly relevant.